# Calcular media geometrica C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

estoy haciendo un programa para calcular las medidas de tendencia central y de dispersion  en un DatagridView pero la que me falta es la media geometrica.Estoy elevando los datos deacuerdo a su frecuencia pero ahora quiero multiplicarlos  es lo que no se como hacer..

ese es el codigo que llevo

```
  //MEDIA GEOMETRICA 
            double total = 0;
            for (int  f= 0; f < Listanumero.RowCount - 1; f++)
            {
                double F = Convert.ToDouble(Listanumero.Rows[f].Cells[1].Value);
                double num= Convert.ToDouble(Listanumero.Rows[f].Cells[0].Value);
                 Listanumero.Rows[f].Cells["MediaG"].Value = Math.Pow(num, F) ;
                double med= Convert.ToDouble(Listanumero.Rows[f].Cells[5].Value);



                mediaGtxt.Text = total.ToString();
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar esa no es la Media Geometrica

La MG es igual a la raiz n-enesima del producto de los elementos

Comment: si lo tengo entendido,pero se necesita elevar los numero de acuerdo a su frecuencia y luego multiplicarlos para entonces si sacarle la raiz n-enesima, gracias por tu respuesta